# How to animate image on rectangular box in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a requirement like:

Provide 4 moving cars which will go by the rectangle.
Their tops should be always outside the rectangle as shown.
When the car will achieve the corner, it should make a turn.
[image]

Can you please provide me some iOS sample code or any idea how can I approach this task?

Comment: have you checked [Sprite Kit](https://developer.apple.com/spritekit/). Have you even tried doing it yourself before posting a question? Please ask specific questions about where you are stuck.

Comment: @ lukya , I will try this SDK, I haven't got any idea how to do this?. That's the reason I posted this question. Please help me out. How could I approach this query?

Comment: You can try [UI View Animations](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewanimating) for simple light weight animations or above mentioned [Sprite Kit](https://developer.apple.com/spritekit/) for better, more involved (and heavy) animations. Try searching for simple iOS animation code (there are MANY tutorials online) and try to implement the animation for one car first and then try to extend it for all 4. And then, if you are stuck at any specific issue/scenario, ask a detailed question with what you have tried, what went wrong, and where you are stuck (with your code snippets).

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to nest four animations. One for each side. Maybe in a recursive method, changing only the center point.

Try this in Playground to get the idea:

```
var container = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 200.0, height: 200.0))
container.clipsToBounds = false
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 20.0, height: 20.0))
view.center = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
container.addSubview(view)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = container

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
    //rotate 90°
   view.center = CGPoint(x: container.frame.size.width, y: 0)
}, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
        //rotate 90°
        view.center = CGPoint(x: container.frame.size.width, y: container.frame.size.height)
    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
        //...        
})
})
```